# Edited and got two points for it but it isn't showing up anywhere in my stats or achivements

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I'm sorry that I can't give you the answer/question I edited with this question but I can't remember what it was, just that I've been on the lookout for day's now for it to show up in my stats/achievements but it just isn't appearing.

I use different computers where I access this site and I've refreshed the cache in my browser if it matters.

I saw the two points appearing in my score but there is no record of the edit. What is wrong/reason for this?

Also it's missing from the actions page(was never there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You edited a question that was then deleted. So, while your edit was approved and you got your +2, you can't see the post in your profile because the question is no longer visible to you.